# Set up windows authentication in Azure

Tags: windows, authentication, azure

Our azure web site have an administrative folder. To login an administrative part we use windows authentication. To set up windows authentication in virtual machines we should set overrideModeDefault="Allow" () in applicationHost.config file and create windows user. My question is how can I specify these actions in deployment package (ServiceDefinition file)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you really require windows authentication? I would recommend to use any other authentication mechanism.

If at all require, then you will have to setup startup task in your azure web role and in that start up task, you can write script to update applicationhost file and create windows user.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) link will help you in creating start up task. For updating applicationhost file and creating windows user, probably you can use powershell.